# Eliminate row after matching process and keep minimum data

Tags: pandas, csv, dataframe

I analyze matching process between two brand data. After analyze, the dataframe looks like this:

```
df
Brand A Type A  Brand B Type B  Data 1  Data 2  Match
IDA     Type A  ID1     Type 1  3.2     403.4   Match-1
IDA     Type B  ID1     Type 2  4.1     403.4   Match-2
IDA     Type A  ID1     Type 1  1.1     56.5    Match-1
IDA     Type B  ID1     Type 2  1.4     56.5    Match-2
IDA     Type B  ID1     Type 2  0.6     220.4   Match-2
IDB     Type A  ID2     Type 1  1.0     292.3   Match-1
IDB     Type B  ID2     Type 2  0.6     292.3   Match-2
IDB     Type A  ID2     Type 1  1.5     472.6   Match-1
```

I want to eliminate brand A and brand b columns or drop the row of `dataframe` but keep `minimum` based on Data 1 and Data 2 columns and match-1 and match-2 (must be a couple of data still exist). forgive me if the explanation not clear.

my expected result looks like this:

```
Result
Brand A Type A  Brand B Type B  Data 1  Data 2  Match
IDA     Type A  ID1     Type 1  1.1     56.5    Match-1
IDA     Type B  ID1     Type 2  1.4     56.5    Match-2
IDB     Type A  ID2     Type 1  1.0     292.3   Match-1
IDB     Type B  ID2     Type 2  0.6     292.3   Match-2
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using `sort_value` then `drop_duplicates`

```
yourdf = df.sort_values(['Data 2','Data 1']).drop_duplicates(['Brand A', 'Type A',  'Brand B', 'Type B'] )
```

The output

```
df.sort_values(['Data 2','Data 1']).drop_duplicates(['Brand A', 'Type A',  'Brand B', 'Type B'] ).sort_index()

  BrandA  TypeA BrandB  TypeB  Data1  Data2    Match
2    IDA  TypeA    ID1  Type1    1.1   56.5  Match-1
3    IDA  TypeB    ID1  Type2    1.4   56.5  Match-2
5    IDB  TypeA    ID2  Type1    1.0  292.3  Match-1
6    IDB  TypeB    ID2  Type2    0.6  292.3  Match-2
```

Comment: - thank you for your answer. however, another row still appear (not only couple data)

Comment: @Arief base on your sample data I get match with your expected output , can you check it again ?

Comment: your result `last` maybe its mean `max`. how about to keep `minimum`?

Comment: @Arief fixed by delete the keep last

Comment: @Arief question why it is not 0.6  220.4 for type2